# Writing the value of al - assembly - real mode - masm

Tags: assembly, masm, real-mode, irvine16

I want to show the value of the register al without using any library, what should I do? Which interrupt should I use? I'm using assembly language (masm) and my program is in real mode.

for example in protected mode we use Irvine32 library:

```
mov bl , al
mov eax , 0
mov al , bl
call WriteInt    ; (showing the value of al)
```

Comment: There's no DOS interrupt for printing numbers. You'll have to convert the number into a string yourself, and then print the string. This has been [asked several times before](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bassembly%5D+print+decimal).

Comment: Isn't there any interrupt If I want to show it in hexadecimal not decimal?

Comment: No. There's no such interrupt regardless of base (well, unless you count ASCII as base128).

Comment: What operating system are you programming for? I assume it's DOS, can you confirm?

Answer (score 1):

If you already have installed the files of Irvine, you can use the `irvine16.lib` library, the 16 bit linker `link16.exe` in the same folder and the MASM assembler `ml.exe` of Visual Studio.

**test.asm**:

```
INCLUDE (Full Path to)\Irvine16.inc
INCLUDELIB (Full Path to)\Irvine16.lib

.code
main PROC
    mov ax,@data
    mov ds,ax

    mov al, 123

    mov bl , al
    mov eax , 0
    mov al , bl
    call WriteInt

    mov ax, 4C00h
    int 21h
main ENDP
```

**build.cmd**:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET LIB=
PATH Path\to\VisualStudio\bin;Path\to\Irvine32

ml.exe /c /omf test.asm
link16.exe test.obj, test.exe;
```

Build it in a command prompt window of Windows just by entering `build.cmd`. To run it, you have eventually change to DOSBox or a similar DOS emulator.

Comment: Also, you can use a Windows XP virtual machine.